# How to use apply function for multiplying 2 in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The below table having 1000 rows but here let's consider 3 rows:

| Date | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-24 | 12 | 1234 |
| 2021-02-01 | 34 | 6789 |
| 2020-04-30 | 23 | 4324 |

I want to multiply all values of B column with 2 and all values of C columns with 3 using apply function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`df.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
df.loc[:, ['B','C']] = df[['B','C']].mul([2,3])

         Date   B      C
0  2022-07-24  24   3702
1  2021-02-01  68  20367
2  2020-04-30  46  12972
```

If set on using `apply`, you could do:

```
df.loc[:, ['B','C']] = df[['B','C']].apply(lambda x: x.mul([2,3]), axis=1)
```

Evidently, this is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, but can you suggest the solution using apply function?